# PHP PDO with Microsoft SQL Server: Prepare Statement issues?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am fairly new to PDO. I am trying to run a query(Microsoft Sql Server). Eventually i am going to add more fields after WHERE.

```
$complex = 'Shipping';
$username= 'username';
$password = 'password';
try {
    $conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=server,1433;Database=dbname', $username, $password);
    $query = "SELECT DATA FROM TrimTable WHERE COMPLEX LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query, array($complex));
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo "$row\n";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried this as well:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=mzrefd39,1433;Database=ger_mapv', $username, $password);
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT AREA FROM TrimTable WHERE COMPLEX LIKE ?");
    $sth->execute(array($complex));
    $data = $sth->fetchAll();
    print_r($data);
}
```

In my page i get Array( ). I am not getting any values?

Comment: `errorInfo` function

Comment: Your `prepare()` call failed.  `if($stmt === FALSE){ var_dump($conn->errorInfo()); }`

Comment: Why are you passing `array($complex)` to `prepare()`?  Have a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @RocketHazmat Check Update.

Comment: Your query returning 0 rows isn't an error.  Are you sure there are errors that match your clause?  You're using `LIKE`, did you forget to add `%`s to your search query?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `bindParam()` before execute, Try this code

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=server,1433;Database=dbname', $username, $password);
$query = "SELECT DATA FROM TrimTable WHERE COMPLEX LIKE ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); // check $complex is removed from this line
$stmt->bindParam(1, $complex);
$stmt->execute();
```

Use `bindParam();` for condition to execute query for conditions

Comment: Hey Down Voter may i know the reason for down vote, we can use bindParam for executing query in PDO right?, thats what my answer, what is the problem in this?